# Usage of two different timestamps in one SQL query

Tags: sql, timestamp

I am stuck on a SQL challenge:
Per day in 2019 the number of page visits and registrations

The dataset looks the following: [image]

I don’t get how I can count both the number of page visits per day and the number of registrations per day as they are based on two different timestamps (users.user_registration_timestamp and informations.info_timestamp)? Do I need to use a subquery? And how would the SQL query look like?

Comment: At first glance you can join the two tables and have a `WHERE` condition to get the relevant records within the desired day and then you can `COUNT` what you want (you may need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT user_ID)` though)

Comment: The column doesn’t matter in isolation. The value does. A “day” is an integral part of any timestamp, regardless of the field it is stored in. Providing the _actual_ challenge requirements would likely add clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a join, you just need to seperate Selects:

```
select cast(user_registration_timestamp as date), count(*)
from users
where user_registration_timestamp >= timestamp '2019-00-01 00:00:00'
  and user_registration_timestamp < timestamp '2020-00-01 00:00:00'
group by cast(user_registration_timestamp as date)

union all

select cast(info_timestamp as date), count(*)
from informations
where info_timestamp >= timestamp '2019-00-01 00:00:00'
  and info_timestamp < timestamp '2020-00-01 00:00:00'
group by cast(info_timestamp as date)
```

This returns two rows, if you want a single row CROSS JOIN both Selects.